# how can i share my comments in googleplus by using addthis

Tags: android

i tried out its not working anyone can help me out

public void googlefunc(View v)

```
{
    try {
        AddThis.shareItem(this, "googleplus", mUrl, mShareTitle,
        mShareDescription);
        } 
        catch (ATDatabaseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ATSharerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `google_plusone` (or `google_plusone_share`) instead of `googleplus`.

See the list of the [available service](http://www.addthis.com/services/list) (and search for `google_plusone` to find the right row).

Comment: Great answer. But you should take care of the presentation to be more clear for others. Look at how I edited it.